# Finding index of raster band with minimum or maximum value using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, multi-band

I am using ArcGIS Desktop and I have a 6-band raster.

How do I output a single-band raster whose values are the band number (1,2,3,4,5 or 6) of which band in the original raster contain the maximum (or minimum) value?

Accounting for ties would be a bonus.

Comment: If you want to also ask about other software please do that in additional questions, one question per software.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to grid format and use http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/highest-position.htm on a list of resulting raster.